# automator fifa 19 web app

Tags: macos, safari, automator, automation

I'm trying to click the reset button in Fifa 19 web app with automator.

[image]

codes I've tried.

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell current tab of window 1
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('btn-standard')[0].click()"
    end tell
end tell
```

second one

> ```
> to clickClassName(theClassName, elementnum)
>
>   tell application "Safari"
>       activate
>
>       do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in current tab of first window
>
>   end tell
>
> end clickClassName
> clickClassName("btn-standard", 0)
> ```

nothing works any idea why ? I know I can do it with watch me do, but I want to click this button with java script.

After some research it seems that they are more btn-standard tags so is there any way to first select the class="button-container and then the class  btn-standard ? Maybe I'm not selecting the button correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applescript/Javascript to click submenu item of Jupiter Notebook in Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336581/applescript-javascript-to-click-submenu-item-of-jupiter-notebook-in-safari)(you should be able to use the same method in the answer there)

Comment: I want to do it with javascript I know it can be done with watch me do

Comment: so you want JavaScript not AppleScript?

Comment: I want to be able to do it in automator with javascript because that's what I need to another button, that button changes the value so it can't be done with normal watch me do, so yea javascript is needed.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('btn-standard')[0].click();" in document 1
end tell
```

---

When in doubt, You can always use [APPLESCRIPT MAKER](http://www.cubemg.com/applescript-maker-beta/)  Which will create the correct JavaScript for you

I'm not really sure because I never use Safari but maybe enabling "Allow JavaScript from Apple Events" Needs to be enabled?

[image]

Comment: still not working, I know in theory all the example should work, but in practice nothing works, I'll give it a try with apple script maker and see what I find out

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running? Are you running the code as an applet Or running the code through script editor?

Comment: running 10.13.6 High Sierra and I'm running the script in an Automator workflow

Comment: Try running that code snippet in Script Editor app… make sure that Safari page has finished loading before you try running the JavaScript code..  Also check out my updated post about "Allow JavaScript from Apple Events" in Safari

Comment: yes it is already enabled from Developer Menu, maybe I should try the script in another browser like firefox

Comment: Try adding a short delay command after your activate command... delay 1

Comment: still not working and it seems Firefox has limited applescript support and this commands won't work.

Comment: maybe I'm not selecting the button class correctly because it seems that they are 10 btn-standard classes on the page