# Automator - is it possible to repeat Watch me Do for each clickable div element in a div list on a webpage

Tags: applescript, safari, automator

I'm trying to have automator click on a series of div buttons that have the same html structure in a long table-list (actually divs) on a webpage. (after clicking each one, do the same thing click on a sub menu button)

How do you repeat an automator Watch me Do based on similar initial div element?

Comment: I'd use JavaScript or AppleScript with JavaScript to do as you've mentioned. It much more efficient. Can you share the URL to the target webpage?

Comment: [Using Javascript | Applescript to click button in Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119324/using-javascript-applescript-to-click-button-in-safari) and [Applescript/Javascript to click submenu item of Jupiter Notebook in Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336581/applescript-javascript-to-click-submenu-item-of-jupiter-notebook-in-safari?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @user3439894 http://beta.aiva.ai - right button of each div list opens download prompt, in which you have to select which format in popup.

Comment: @user3439894 insight appreciated thanks!